# Best way to serve a custom image, and storing of same

Tags: java, web-services, asp-classic

I have a need for 3 different applications to serve images that are customizable (and maintainable) by my users.

The dev staff as agreed that one of the three applications will assume the responsibility for image maintenance.  That is, our users can log into the app (as per normal) and use a new web page to upload, view, and deleted images.  The images are logos; we're branding our site on a per user basis, basically.

- We could have tens of thousands of logos eventually.  They're likely to be 30k to 50k each and a mix of pnh, gif, and jpegs. Would the collective wisdom of SO say to put them in the database, or save them on the file system with the database being used to index the files?  I know that CMS systems tend to utilize the file system but this seems odd to me.
- How would we serve these images? We span technologies in our company as some apps are old.

  - a)  One developer recommends building an **asp** that pulls the image
    from our database using a SQL query.  The URL of this asp would be used as the source for IMG tags.  This asp can apparently be
    used by any of our three applications to pull images. He says this is
    very lightweight and will allow browsers to cache the images.
  - b)  The **Java** developer recommends building a web service that allows an image to be fetched from the database. This seems to me to be very reasonable but how are these images served?

I am not an oppressive manager.  I leave technical issues to the developers. However, they can't seem to agree on the technique so it will be for me to decide.  I require one solution, not one per application/technology.

In addition to answers to the questions above, I'd appreciate pros/con comments on the asp page vs web service solutions presented above.  For example, the asp programmer says that the web service technique (where the web service is called server side) causes the images be converted to BASE64 before being sent to the browser, making caching impossible and increasing the effective size of the web page.

I'm looking for the best solution, not the trendy one or the cheapest one.

I'm off to Google!

Comment: It's really a case of personal preference each method has it pros and cons but I just want to point out that your ASP programmer it's completely wrong about not being able to cache a database image. You can do this by creating a page that pulls the image based on an identifier and adds the relevant headers to allow it to be cached. Something like `/dbimage.asp?id=1` the page pulls the image data back as a jpeg, png, gif etc based on content type you store in the database at point of upload. The Base64 comment is nonsense.